# Losing scope variables after a routing redirection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build my first CRUD Application using AngularJS.

I made some PHP web services for those CRUD operations and all is good.

The problem happens when i want to edit a specific user(object in `ng-repeat`).

I want to pass it  from `page(listUsers.html)` to an other `page(addUser.html)` so that i can show his properties in input's.

I have only one controller and i use routing.

**Brief Example :**

In ListUsers.html i have a button that calls update() on click and then redirect me to AddUser.html  :

```
app1.controller('testController',function($scope,$http){

    $scope.update=function(e){
        $scope.message="testeeee";
        $scope.newStudentt = e;
    };
});
```

How can i pass `$scope.message` to AddUser.html ??

Comment: do you have jsfiddle example?

Comment: anyway I would like to see your angular code and see error

Comment: You can only have one ng-view per application.

Comment: @Neikos , sorry , i edited the title of post

Comment: We would still need the whole application code. It looks like you are not using the router. (Since you talk about files.)

Comment: i get html pages using ajax requests handled by angular , routing works correctly

Comment: What is `page(listUsers.html)` then?

Comment: it's my main page loaded by routing in a ng-view , it contains update button for editing users , what i want is passing this user to addUser page using update() called when i click on update button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use service to pass things around:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl%3aeTYOsTVTLXNGR1yZZcbX?p=preview)</kbd>

```
app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, UserService, $location) {
  // Fetch users from the server
  $scope.users = [
    {name: 'Jesse', email: 'jesse@example.com'},
    {name: 'Walter', email: 'ww@example.com'}
  ];

  $scope.update = function(user){
    UserService.setUser(user);
    $location.url('/user/edit');
  };
});

app.controller('EditUserCtrl', function($scope, UserService, $location) {
  $scope.user = UserService.getUser();

  $scope.save = function(){
    // Implement logic for saving to server
    alert('Saved');
  };

});

app.service('UserService', function(){
  var editingUser;
  this.setUser = function(user){
    editingUser = user;
  };

  this.getUser = function(){
    return editingUser;
  }
});
```

Comment: Very helpful thanks , i thought i need service.Thank you for this snippet